# Angular 2 Testing Component with sinon - component is undefined

Tags: angular, karma-runner

I'm trying to test a simple (yet more complicated-seeming) than the Angular team's [quickstart](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/testing.html#) tutorial. I've tried looking at a dozen or so other articles, but perhaps because of the "fluid" nature of the ng2 framework the last 6 - 12 months, there are quite a few resources out there that seem dated now.

I'm using Angular 2 version 2.4.10, Typescript, Sinon version 2.1.0, and Webpack 2 (also ag-grid, if it matters).

Component Code:

**updated question to include OtherService in the constructor, which I had missed when I first copied this over**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { GridOptions } from "ag-grid";
import { EventDataService } from "./data-service/event-data.service";
import { OtherService } from "./data-service/other.service";
import { ColumnDefs } from "../shared/event-grid/event-grid-column-defs";
import { Event } from "./event/event.interface";
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Rx";

@Component({
    templateUrl: "./event-list.component.html",
    styleUrls: ["./event-list.component.scss"]
})

export class EventListComponent implements OnInit {

    // grid data & settings
    private gridOptions: GridOptions;
    private columnDefs: any;

    // auto refresh / event-service messaging settings
    public loadingEvents: boolean;

    // main data array = holds event list displayed by grid
    private events: Event[];

    // updated question with privateOtherService, which I had missed when I first copied this over
    constructor(private eventDataService: EventDataService, private otherService: OtherService) {

        // initialize grid
        this.gridOptions = <GridOptions>{};
        this.gridOptions.columnDefs = ColumnDefs;

        // initialize flag to indicate we are waiting for events from service
        this.loadingEvents = false;
    }

    beginPollingLoop(): void {
        this.getEvents();

        // ... other logic that will repeat the getEvents call periodically...
    };

    getEvents() {
        this.loadingEvents = true;

        // treats response from event service as an observable to subscribe to
        return this.eventDataService.getEvents()
            .subscribe(
            (events: Event[]) => { this.events = events; },
            (error: any) => // handle errors,
            () => {this.loadingEvents = false; });
    };

    ngOnInit(): void {
        // begin polling loop (using defaults) once component loads
        this.beginPollingLoop();
    }
}
```

Spec Code:

```
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from "@angular/core/testing";
import { expect } from "chai";
import { spy } from "sinon";
import { EventListComponent } from "./event-list.component";

// dependency of component
import { EventDataService } from "./data-service/event-data.service";
import { AgGridModule } from "ag-grid-angular/main";

let component: EventListComponent;
let fixture: ComponentFixture<EventListComponent>;

let spies = {
    beginPollingLoop: {}
};

let eventServiceStub = {
    getEvents: Observable.from([])
};

describe("EventListComponent", () => {

    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [AgGridModule.withComponents([])],
            declarations: [ EventListComponent ],
            providers: [{ provide: EventDataService, useValue: eventServiceStub }]
        });
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(EventListComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance; // component is undefined

        spies.beginPollingLoop = spy(component, "beginPollingLoop");
    });

    describe("EventListComponent", () => {
        describe("When the component initializes", () => {
            it("should set loadingEvents to 'false'", () => {
                expect(component.loadingEvents).to.be.true;
            });
        });

        describe("when OnInit() runs", () => {
            let beginPollingLoop = spy(component, "beginPollingLoop");
            expect(beginPollingLoop.called).to.equal(true);
        });    
    });
});
```

The specific error I'm getting in my console is "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'beginPollingLoop' of undefined". According to the debugger, the `component` is what is undefined. On my screen, Karma's test output error message is: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'injector' of null"

I feel like I'm building the Testbed as indicated by the docs, so I can only assume I'm somehow not registering all the dependencies of my component correctly. This is causing my `component` to not be created correctly.

Thanks!

Comment: Replace `expect(beginPollingLoop.called).to.equal(true);` with `expect(component.beginPollingLoop).toBeCalled();` and may be you should invoke ngOnInit manually in test to true this condition

Comment: @BabarBilal I believe that will just be changing which `expect` syntax I use, but not solve the issue of `component` being undefined. That's what's causing the issue: `spies.beginPollingLoop = spy(component, "beginPollingLoop");` --> component is undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the issue. In the spec, `component` was "undefined" because when `TestBed` tried to create the `component`, it was failing because I had an additional service being used in the constructor for `EventListComponent` that I was not accounting for in my spec. Once I realized this and stubbed that service out in my spec as well, the component created fine.

That was the root of the issue - I just didn't see it because the error Angular was throwing was being buried somewhere deep inside it's own code. Instead of something useful like "TestBed failed to create component: constructor argument mismatch" or something helpful, I was seeing errors related to other things trying to use the component which I assumed had been created successfully. This made it unclear that the component had not been created, and *why* it had failed: the component I was creating was not being fed the arguments it's constructor expected.

So the final spec looked like:

```
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from "@angular/core/testing";
import { expect } from "chai";
import { spy } from "sinon";
import { EventListComponent } from "./event-list.component";

// dependency of component
import { EventDataService } from "./data-service/event-data.service";
import { OtherService } from "./data-service/other.service";

let component: EventListComponent;
let fixture: ComponentFixture<EventListComponent>;

let eventServiceStub = {
    getEvents: Observable.from([])
};

// forgot this one
let otherServiceStub = {
    getStuff: () => {}
};

describe("EventListComponent", () => {

    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [],
            declarations: [ EventListComponent ],
            providers: [
                { provide: EventDataService, useValue: eventServiceStub },
                { provide: OtherDataService, useValue: otherServiceStub } // this was missing
            ]
        });
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(EventListComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance; // component is undefined
    });

    describe("EventListComponent", () => {
        describe("when OnInit() runs", () => {
            let beginPollingLoop = spy(component, "beginPollingLoop");
                expect(beginPollingLoop.called).to.equal(true);
            });    
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you. That helped me too. Hope the Angular team spends some time on improving the testing frameworks soon.